# Adding primary key on datatable

Tags: c#, linq, select, datatable

I have been trying to improve performance using `DataTable.Select` by adding a Primary Key to the Table but its still taking way too much time merely for 1200 rows. With and without Primary Key the difference in time is only 3-4 seconds (for `DataTable.Select`).

Now, as far as i know, Linq's performance is not affected by the Primary Key addition for sure. The performance for me is useless due to the creation of Datarow collection array which is the bottleneck i guess.

Then what is the use of a Primary Key at all here?

Comment: Its more or less a thing used in connection with the backend DB behind the DataTable. For pure local data a pk would only be helpfull with certain things like merging. Whats the reason behind this comparison? Using a DataTable without a Backend looks like a bad choice when not knowing more details.

Comment: @Ralf - `a pk would only be helpfull with certain things like merging` Merging what? Can you explain. My purpose is a selection for may be 200-300 rows in a loop. Hence i want the selection to be fast.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think the PK is a constraint and doesn't create an index.

Comment: I meant function like DataTable.Merge for example that uses the PK to match rows between the 2 datatables going to be merged.

Comment: @PaoloCosta I thought so too, and even posted an earlier incorrect answer to that effect, but actually, it turns out a PK does create an index internally, and it's possible to make use of that index.

Answer (score 1):

A `DataTable`'s primary key does internally maintain an index, separately from the row order, and you're right that `Select` could be optimised to treat a filter on primary key as a special case. Unfortunately, this hasn't been done, and `Select` simply goes through all the records, one by one, and evaluates the filter.

The reason this is still slower than your LINQ version is because the filter you pass in as a string first needs to be parsed, then it gets converted to an expression tree (not the LINQ version of expression trees), and an expression evaluator then acts as an interpreter. Your LINQ version generates CIL code that performs the filtering, which will be converted to native code at run-time. No interpreter required.

You can get benefits of the primary key by using [`DataRowCollection.Find`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ydd48eyk%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
var rows = lst.Select(key => dtsrc.Rows.Find(key)).Where(row => row != null).ToList();
```

If `lst` might contain duplicate keys, you'd need to remove them first. You could use the [`Enumerable.Distinct()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb348436%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) method, or you might use a `HashSet<int>` right from the start (if you don't care about the order of your rows).

(I earlier claimed that the `Select` method couldn't be optimised, because the primary key information was not saved in any way that a method could make use of, but I was wrong about that, as my example now shows.)